# Checkstyle method name rule regexp modification

Tags: regex, sonarqube, checkstyle

I am running Sonar and checkstyle has a regexp rule like this:

```
^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

I would like to modify it so that one or more underscores are allowed. How would I change this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

If you want to allow underscores anywhere:

```
^[a-z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$
```

If you want to allow underscores anywhere except the first character:

```
^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$
```